# Crosswalk integration visualstudio cordova

Tags: android, cordova, crosswalk

I am trying to do crosswalk integration but it does not work.

I have done:

1-) Created Cordova project(Typecript)

2-) Add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview

3-) Buil Android device

4-) debug Ripple Nexus S

> ```
> navigator.UserAgent : Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.3.2; en-us; 
> Nexus S Build/GRH78C) AppleWebKit/533.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0
> Mobile Safari/533.1
> and apk size: 400 kb
> ```

What I do wrong?

Good day. thanks.

Comment: Did you try on device ?

Comment: yes. I installed Android 4.4 , Android 4.2 real device and visual studio smulator but the result is the same.

Comment: I need to copy source files for embedded?  Copying files for older versions of crosswalk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

> C:\a\a\platforms\android\cordova clean.bat run

Final state:
1-) Create Cordova project
2-) Build Device
3-) run C:\a\a\platforms\android\cordova clean.bat 
4-) add Add cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview
5-) Build device